# Migration: No DbContext was found in assembly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, dbcontext, entity-framework-migrations

Using VS Community 2017. I have tried to create initial migration with error message saying:

> Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework 6.
>   No DbContext was found in assembly 'Test_Project'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

... code in my dbcontext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(mb);

    mb.Entity<Stuff>().ToTable("Stuff");

}

public DbSet<Stuff> Stuff{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core, also with `dotnet ef migrations add Initial`/`dotnet ef database update` command instead of `Add-Migration`/`Update-Database` in PM console? There are some missing points you need to explain here.

Comment: It's a MVC project using EF Core. I tried "dotnet ef migrations add" but gave me message: "dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef""

Comment: Well, I think you can look for this first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations. If you have EF 6 with Core MVC try to use EF Core & remove EF 6 references.

Comment: "Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed." - is that on purpose? Because I would go out of my way to avoid that.

Comment: Ok, I have uninstalled EF Core keeping only EF 6. Now after I ran 'enable-migrations' and 'add-migration Initial' all works. Thanks guys.

Comment: I used 'EntityFramework\Add-Migration' and 'EntityFramework\Update-Database' when I got this error message, but I guess like Henk Holterman says the two framework should not be installed at one time...

Answer (score 41):

In the Package Manager Console, select the Project where the **class** that inherits `DbContext` is defined. Then, run the command `add-migration initial`.

Comment: How to select the project? Facing the same issue and no idea how to select a project in the console.

Comment: In the console you can navigate with the cd (change directory) command

Comment: How about on Mac, where the Package Manager Console is not available?

Comment: try `dotnet ef migrations add Initial`

Answer (score 28):

You have to specify the project name where the `DbContext` is located. So just right on the NuGet PM Console, type: `Add-Migration MigrationName -Project YourProjectName`.

Comment: This answer helped me because I am working in a solution that contains multiple projects. Thanks.

Comment: I am also working on a solution that contains multiple projects, and I use this answer with `update-database -Project YourProjectName` and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.
In my case the starter project was <ProjectName>.Api and other project was <ProjectName>.Core . I had all the migration and database stuff in Core.  I Was getting error like : No DbContext was found in assembly '<ProjectName>.Api'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.
I finally used the commands: 
Add-Migration MigrationName -Project YourProjectName.
update-database -Project YourProjectName
And it worked like a charm.

Comment: Worked a treat for me Visual Studio 2022 Preview .NET6 EF 6.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Using the nuget package manager, I had installed all the EntityFrameworkCore dependencies, along with the EntityFramework 6 dependency. Visual Studio was using EF Core, when I needed it to be using EF 6. Uninstalling all EF Core dependencies resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue, I had just renamed an existing project to "EF", then renamed all namespaces to "EF".  What worked for me was I changed the Assembly name to something other than "EF" (Project properties/Application/Assembly Name).  I was using VS Community 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the visual studio and restart your project and then write command again. It worked for me twice

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and restarting it did help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by renaming the project, before that it coincided with the name of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just close the visual studio and re-open and execute the command, If you are using PowerShell for migration use below command.

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
```

If you need to reset the database

```
dotnet ef database drop --force --context DbContext_ClassName
```