# How to manage EF migration within .NET MAUI APP

Tags: .net, entity-framework, database-migration, maui

EF CORE and .NET MAUI (to my knowladge) don't work together perfectly. I tried to make a migration using EF with .NET MAUI APP however it ended up not nicely:

,,Startup project 'MyJOfficial' targets platform 'Android'. The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support this platform. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-pmc-tfms for more information."

There is an explanation on how to overcome this problem online,

,,The Package Manager Console tools work with .NET Core or .NET Framework projects. Apps that have the EF Core model in a .NET Standard class library might not have a .NET Core or .NET Framework project. For example, this is true of Xamarin and Universal Windows Platform apps. In such cases, you can create a .NET Core or .NET Framework console app project whose only purpose is to act as startup project for the tools. The project can be a dummy project with no real code — it is only needed to provide a target for the tooling.

Why is a dummy project required? As mentioned earlier, the tools have to execute application code at design time. To do that, they need to use the .NET Core or .NET Framework runtime. When the EF Core model is in a project that targets .NET Core or .NET Framework, the EF Core tools borrow the runtime from the project. They can't do that if the EF Core model is in a .NET Standard class library. The .NET Standard is not an actual .NET implementation; it's a specification of a set of APIs that .NET implementations must support. Therefore .NET Standard is not sufficient for the EF Core tools to execute application code. The dummy project you create to use as startup project provides a concrete target platform into which the tools can load the .NET Standard class library."

but it does not work properly.

I have created a .NET C# console app and put it in my solution with the app itself but the problem still exists and after selecting it as default project and startup project I'm getting an error:

,,No DbContext was found in assembly 'dla_narzedi2'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic."

I find it strange since in the solution it clearly states that ,,The project can be a dummy project with no real code", but maybe I just don't understand something. How exacly can I use this solution? Did I do it right or I messed it up?

Comment: About this error: "No DbContext was found in assembly...", you can refer to this case:[Migration: No DbContext was found in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76503789/19902734).